# making a loop to display buttons

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a loop that will display some images and add an event listener to each image which, when clicked will assign the appropriate value to humanGoal. I have:

```
var humanGoal;

function displayPicker(round){
    for(var i = 0; i <= round; i++){
        document.write('<img src=img/die' + i + '.png id="' + 'picker' + i + '">');
        document.getElementById('picker'+i).addEventListener("click", function () {
            humanGoal = i;
            document.write('you picked ' + humanGoal );
        });
    }
}
```

why does humanGoal always === round+1, instead of the variable i from the for loop?

Comment: try i.toString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `humanGoal` variable is being overwrited with every `for` loop iteration and holds the `round` + 1 value at the end. Different words speaking - it will always display a wrong index.

Solution: apply same class to the each `img` element, bind a `click` event listener and display the actual `index` by passing `i` variable inside the `Array#forEach` function.

```js
function displayPicker(round){
    for (var i = 0; i <= round; i++){
      document.write('<img src=img/die' + i + '.png id="' + 'picker' + i + '" class="img">');
    }
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('img');
        Array.from(elems).forEach((v,i) => v.addEventListener('click', function() {
          console.log(`You picked ${i}`);
        }));
}

displayPicker(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

See answer to your question is simple, when you were trying to assign human goal with value of i, the loop is already been iterated over "rounds" value that why you always getting **i === round** inside click function.

See the below code snippet,

```html
<html>
 <script>
 var humanGoal;

  function displayPicker(round){
   for(var i = 0; i <= round; i++){
    document.write('<img src=img/die' + i + '.png id="' + 'picker' + i + '">');
    document.getElementById('picker'+i).addEventListener("click", function () {
     console.log("me getting called second");
     humanGoal = i;
     document.body.append('you picked ' + humanGoal );
    });
    console.log("me getting called first");
   }
  }
 
 </script>
 <body onload="displayPicker(4)">
 </body>
</html>
```

for getting the correct result you can follow the approach provided by @Kind user